# How to use own user table instead of apache activiti workflow?

Tags: java, activiti

I want to integrate Activiti workflow with my Java application but I want to use my own user table instead of activiti `act_id_user` table and want to make relation of my user table with activiti database, is this possible? If yes then please provide me a demo application of workflow with java for reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "make relation of my user table with activiti database"?  Do you want to use an external user table with the Activiti engine, or do you want to actually perform SQL joins between some other user table and Activiti tables?

Comment: Both. I want to use external user table and also want joins between own user table and activiti database.According to my R&D i need to create my own identity service but i also want to use **UI of activiti explorer**, is this possible to use activiti explorer ui with my application and with my own user table. sorry i m asking a lot of questions bcoz i m new to activiti so plz help me its urgent

Answer (score 1):

Kamal,

You are correct in your belief that you will need to create a custom identity provider.
And, if you want to be able to have users login through the Activiti Explorer, you will need to link your user authentication service into the standard Activiti session manager.

The good news is that this is really not a difficult task.

Check out the following Activiti Forum post for a "strawman" of how to handle this:

http://forums.activiti.org/content/separating-out-user-management

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: After writing this answer I started to do a little google searching for a better example. Unfortunately some of the basics like this are not well documented. The following article should add some additional detail for you:

http://developer4life.blogspot.com/2012/02/activiti-authentication-and-identity.html

Comment: As the url <a href="http://forums.activiti.org/content/separating-out-user-management">http://forums.activiti.org/content/separating-out-user-management<a> says that if we are using embedded engine in our application we don't need any external indetity service to use so can we also remove the identity related tables from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Activiti has provided for us such entrance which has been used by the 'activiti ldap' module. But one question is how the customized classes can be identified by the activiti engine, and how to register them.

1. Define sub-SessionFactory classes
2. make activiti engine use your defined classes every time.

Because 'SessionFactory' in the Activiti Engine maintains a specific data structure below

```
HashMap<SessionType, Session>
```

So the sub-SessionFactory classes we registered will cover the old ones which are loaded when the activiti engine started. And then, it is definitely that the engine will read our own management Factory every time.

This [newest blog](https://github.com/xiabin1235910/Activiti-Article/blob/master/use-customized-usermangement-in-activiti.md) may help you! Thank you.